# SQL Redshift - Select rows from similar rows in table that meet a certain criteria

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, greatest-n-per-group

| event_id | alert_id | alert_timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | 2022-10-10 | -2 |
| 1 | x | 2022-10-10 | 4 |
| 1 | x | 2022-10-10 | 5 |
| 2 | z | 2022-09-02 | 3 |

I have a table that has rows that match on `event_id`, `alert_id` and `alert_timestamp`. I want to only keep the single row that has the smallest value in the `value` column where all other rows are matching on `event_id`, `alert_id` and `alert_timestamp`.

NOTE: this is just one example of matching rows, the table has a mix of different rows than the example given, that match on `event_id`, `alert_id` and `alert_timestamp`

Also if there are single rows i.e. a row that has no other row that matches on `event_id`, `alert_id` and `alert_timestamp`, this should be kept as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typical top-1-per-group problem. In Redshift you can use `row_number()` to solve it:

```
select event_id, alert_id, alert_timestamp, value
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by event_id, alert_id, alert_timestamp order by value) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Note that if you *really* had only 4 columns, then aggregation would be sufficient:

```
select event_id, alert_id, alert_timestamp, min(value) as value
from mytable
group by event_id, alert_id, alert_timestamp, value
```

Comment: thanks, for the top answer it returns null values for rows that are singular - how can we ensure those are included?

Comment: @Ossz: I am not sure what you can *singular row*. Are you able to build a small test case that demonstrates the problem, eg on https://dbfiddle.uk/?

Comment: I added an additional row to the table above as an example. Basically the singular row is one that does not have any other matches on the aforementioned fields, I would want this to stay as is post the "top-1-per-group" processing if that makes sense?

Comment: @Ossz: OK I understand. Well, the query does leave *singular rows* as they are, which is what you expect.